# Connect .Net web app to a MySQL DB all in AWS

Tags: mysql, amazon-ec2, .net, amazon-web-services

What do I need to do to allow my web app running on Win2k8 in AWS to connect to my MySQL database server also running in AWS?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to make sure mysql is listening on the 10. address. Also in the mysql security group you want to add the application security group so that they can talk to each other.

Hope that helps.